# How to pass data from one screen to other screen in React Native

Tags: react-native

**1. index.android.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import Button from 'react-native-button';

class AwesomeProject extends Component {

constructor(props){
super(props)

this.state = {
  username: '',
  email: '',
  address: '',
  mobileNumber: ''
 }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

      <TextInput
      ref={component => this.txt_input_name = component}
      style={styles.textInputStyle}
      placeholder="Enter Name"
      returnKeyLabel = {"next"}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username:text})}
      />

      <Button style={styles.buttonStyle}>
      Submit
      </Button> 
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
 buttonStyle: {
   alignSelf: 'center',
   textAlign: 'center',
   color: '#FFFFFF', 
   fontSize:18,
   marginTop:20,
   marginBottom:20,
   padding:5,
   borderRadius:5,
   borderWidth:2,
   width:100,
   alignItems: 'center',
   backgroundColor:'#4285F4',
   borderColor:'#000000'
}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('AwesomeProject', () => AwesomeProject);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the props to another page using navigator

```
 this.props.navigator.push({
    name: 'Home',
    passProps: {
      name: property
    }
  })
```

i took this from this link https://medium.com/@dabit3/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.6yrqn523n

Comment: navigator is component in react-native

Comment: inside a function :?

Answer (score 0):

Initially

```
import {Navigator}
```

Define Navigator inside the

> render

function of

> index.android.js

like this

```
render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'HomePage', name: 'Index'}}
          renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
          configureScene={(route) => {
            if (route.sceneConfig) {
              return route.sceneConfig;
            }
            return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
          }} />
    );
}
```

Then define the

> renderscene function

like this

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
    var routeId = route.id;
    if (routeId === 'HomePage') {
      return (
        <HomePage
          navigator={navigator} />
      );
    }
    if (routeId === 'DetailPage') {
      return (
        <DetailPage
          navigator={navigator}

          {...route.passProps} 
          />
      );
    }

}
```

Specify the property

> {...route.passProps}

for passing values to a screen. Here I have given it inside the `DetailPage`

Then you can use

> passProps

for calling the next page. In my case

> DetailPage

```
this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'DetailPage',
      name: 'DetailPage',
      passProps: {
      name:value

    }
});
```